# In Chrome extension, content_scripts matches are being ignored

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I am new to javascript and attempting to learn Chrome extensions.  I have searched every variation of my question I can think of but the answers I've found don't work for my specific problem.  I have gone through the tutorials for chrome extensions and what I think should be working does not in fact work.

The extension I wrote has no html page, just an icon as it should run all the time.  It actually works perfectly, blocking calls to a certain chat program to prevent the chat window from opening.  It was written for testers who have to be on a site a long time and don't want to keep closing the chat window.

The problem is that the extension works for all websites, and I only want it to work for one website.  That is, the chat window is also blocked when the user is on other websites that use the same chat software.

What I read led me to believe that putting a match to the website I want to use in the content_scripts block of the manifest.json would cause the extension to only run in that matched site.  It does not work.  In fact, if I take the content_scripts block out of the manifest file entirely, the extension works exactly the same. The javascript function is called and the chat window is blocked.  So for some reason the content_scripts block is being ignored.  As a javascript noob, I guess I must be missing a crucial step.  I got most of this code from examples and just modified it slightly. Can anyone help?

manifest.json:

```
    {
  "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
  "name": "ChatBlock",
  "description": "Shut down liveperson chat on mywebsite.com before it runs.",

  "permissions": [          
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://sales.liveperson.net/"
   ],
   "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js"],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.mywebsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
    }
   ],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "chatblockIcon.png"
   },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["avoid.js"]
   }

  }
```

javascript file (avoid.js):

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) {   
    return {
        cancel: true
        }; 
  },
  {urls: ["*://sales.liveperson.net/*"]},
  ["blocking"]);
```

EDIT: I have removed the references to jquery from my manifest.  The tool still works without it just the same, so the comment below was correct, it was not needed - thanks @ExpertSystem.  But the blocking still occurs on all websites. I had previously (before posting this question) tried @ExpertSystem's second suggestion of explicity checking the tabs for the desired website, or checking the referrer, but I was not able to find the correct javascript syntax to make it work.  Also, I am very interested in using the "matches" property if possible so the javascript is more generic.  I am still confused as to why "matches" is not working - what am I doing wrong with regard to the matches property?

New version of Manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
  "name": "ChatBlock",
  "description": "Shut down liveperson chat on myWebsite.com before it runs.",

  "permissions": [          
    "tabs",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://sales.liveperson.net/"
   ],
   "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.myWebsite.com/*"],
      "js": ["avoid.js"]
    }
   ],
   "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "chatblockIcon.png"
   },
   "background": {
    "scripts": ["avoid.js"]
   }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, @ExpertSystem, for your comment.  Per your suggestion I removed the jquery in the manifest.json as you seemed to be saying there was no need for it in the little javascript snippet I was using.  See my edit above.  I am still interested in understanding why the "matches" property in the content_scripts block doesn't work.  Am I using it incorrectly?

Comment: Your "matches" property does work, but injecting `avoid.js` as a content script does not have any effect, because `chrome.webRequest` is not available to content scripts. Your `avoid.js` in background page does work, but it has no way of distinguishing the origin of a request, so they block requests to liveperson.com from **all** tabs. (BTW, it is a bad idea to run the same script as content script and as background page.)

Comment: It worked perfectly @ExpertSystem.  Thank you so much for your help (above and beyond the call of duty, I might add).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are injecting jquery as your content-script, but on her own she's useless. Additionaly, you are listening for webRequests to `liveperson.com` in the background page and cancelling them for every site.

You must device a way to distinguish requests coming from `mywebsite.com` and only block them. (I, also, don't see any reason for injecting jquery.)

Possible ways to distinguish requests might be:

1. Through a header in `details.requestHeaders` (if `mywebsite.com` sets such an appropriate header, e.g. `referer`).
2. Keeping track of open tabs running `mywebsite.com` in background page (by means of a `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener) and filtering webRequests based on `details.tabId`.

...but I'm sure there are plenty more.

---

My demo implementation of the second option above...

**manifest.json:**

```
...
"background": {
    // Unfortunately, chrome.webRequest 
    // requires a persistent background page
    "persistent": true,
    "scripts": [
        "background.js"
    ]
},

"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
            "*://<website1>/*",
            "*://<website2>/*",
            ...
        ],
        "js":         ["content.js"],
        "run_at":     "document_idle",
        "all_frames": false
    }
 ],

"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "*://sales.liveperson.net/*"
]
```

**content.js:**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ text: "block_me" });
```

**background.js:**

```
// Add a tab ID to the blocking list
function addToList(tabId) {
    localStorage.setItem(tabId, "1");
    console.log("Added to list: tab " + tabId);
    console.log("Currently blocking tabs: ", localStorage);
}

// Checks if a tab ID is in the blocking list
function isInList(tabId) {
    return (localStorage.getItem(tabId) !== null);
}

// Remove a tab ID from the blocking list
function removeFromList(tabId) {
    localStorage.removeItem(tabId);
    console.log("Removed from list: tab " + tabId);
    console.log("Currently blocking: ", localStorage);
}

// Listen for messages from content scripts
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender) {
    if (msg.text && (msg.text == "block_me")) {
        addToList(sender.tab.id);
    }
});

// Stop blocking a tab when its is closed
chrome.tabs.onRemoved.addListener(removeFromList);

// Stop blocking a tab when its is updated
// (If applicable, the newly injected content script will notify us.)
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, info, tab) {
    if (info.status && (info.status == "loading")) {
        removeFromList(tabId);
    }
});


// Handle a web-request, i.e. either allow it or block it
function handleRequest(details) {
    var block = isInList(details.tabId);
    console.log("Request from tab " + details.tabId + " - Blocked: " + block);
    console.log("Request details: ", details);
    return { cancel: block };
}

// Block any request to 'sales.liveperson.net',
// if it originates from a tab in our blocking list.
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        handleRequest,
        { urls: ["*://sales.liveperson.net/*"] },
        ["blocking"]);
```

(For production deployment, you can remove the `console.log` calls.)